# Is there a table element in mosaico?

Tags: civimail, mosaico

Still getting to grips with Mosaico layouts. Is there an option to build/ style a table in the templates?

Someone has pasted in a table from an external source and doesn't want to edit font sizes in html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no table elements/blocks that you can add currently. You could try editing the source of a text block an adding manually however it sounds like this isn't ideal in this instance.

To add a table element you'd need to customise the html template itself.

If this was something you wanted to do you could use this extension which adds some additional template elements as a starting point.

https://lab.civicrm.org/MikeyMJCO/mjcomosaico

Comment: Thanks Luke!

I was just wanting to confirm I wasn't going mad/ overlooking the obvious.

I'll go back to the user and say that's not an available option at the moment.